# What is the proper way to include a PHP framework into my theme?

Tags: php, include

I am using a [Twitter Timeline PHP framework](https://github.com/kmaida/twitter-timeline-php) to display a list of tweets with favorite/retweet interactions. I have it all configured and working as a standalone solution currently and I am wondering what the best way to incorporate it into my custom Wordpress theme would be. Is it as simple as creating an `inc` folder, placing all the files in there and then adding `<?php include_once('inc/twitter.php'); ?>` into my template file where I want the tweets to display? Or is there a better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is that simple.  Code away!

if it's in a plugin I do this:

```
$plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
include_once($plugin_url . 'inc/twitter.php');
```

if it's in a theme file

```
include_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'inc/twitter.php');
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the explanation of both methods!

Comment: FYI, using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is incorrect because it will return the URL path to the file, not the path suitable for including the file. Also, it will return the path to the child theme if you have one, which you probably don't want happening either. Use `get_template_directory()` instead.

Comment: why on earth would you not want to use a child theme if you're custom coding?

Comment: If you're, you know, developing a theme? Where do you think parent themes come from?

Comment: Also, these days there's more useful functions: `get_theme_file_path( 'inc/twitter.php' )` and `get_parent_theme_file_path( 'inc/twitter.php' )`. Because the path to the file is an argument you can have a parent theme fallback for non template files.